# How do I create a script in PHP that does the exactly the same as this HTML form?

Tags: php, html, forms, api

I am trying to create a PHP script that does the same as the HTML form below.

The end goal is that I can automate the form with a PHP script. Right now, we must fill the form manually. That was fine in the beginning, but now we must fill the form way too many times every month.

The form below works (if I fill in the correct merchant and ticket). But somehow, I cannot create a PHP script that can do the same.

---

```
<form method="post" action="https://payment.architrade.com/cgi-ssl/ticket_auth.cgi" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="DKK">
    <input type="hidden" name="merchant" value="INSERT_YOUR_MERCHANT_ID">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderid" value="Order_ID-123">
    <input type="hidden" name="textreply" value="true">
    <input type="hidden" name="ticket" value="1234567890">
</form>
```

---

### Here is the code that I have tried (I know the URL is wrong, but I am using an echo service, so I can see the response):

```
$postData = array(
    'amount' => '100',
    'currency' => 'DKK',
    'merchant' => 'INSERT_YOUR_MERCHANT_ID',
    'orderId' => 'Order_ID-123',
    'textreply' => 'true',
    'ticket' => '1234567890'
    );

// Setup cURL
$ch = curl_init('https://postman-echo.com/post');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'content-type: application/x-www-form-data'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
));

// Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo "<br>";
echo 'Response: '. $response;
echo "<br>";
```

---

If you want to know more about the API, you can find some information here:
https://tech.dibspayment.com/D2/API/Payment_functions/ticketauthcgi

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Please let me know if you have any questions

One user (aponte_alex) asked me to make more debug information, so here it is:

```
Array ( [url] => https://postman-echo.com/post [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0 [http_version] => 0 [protocol] => 0 [ssl_verifyresult] => 0 [scheme] => )
{"args":{},"data":"","files":{},"form":{},"headers":{"x-forwarded-proto":"https","host":"postman-echo.com","content-length":"0","accept":"*/*","accept-encoding":"gzip","content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","user-agent":"php","x-forwarded-port":"443"},"json":null,"url":"https://postman-echo.com/post"}
```

If I add json_encode($data) I get the following data:

```
Array ( [url] => https://postman-echo.com/post [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0 [http_version] => 0 [protocol] => 0 [ssl_verifyresult] => 0 [scheme] => )
{"args":{},"data":"","files":{},"form":{"{\"amount\":\"100\",\"currency\":\"DKK\",\"merchant\":\"INSERT_YOUR_MERCHANT_ID\",\"orderId\":\"Order_ID-123\",\"textreply\":\"true\",\"ticket\":\"1234567890\"}":""},"headers":{"x-forwarded-proto":"https","host":"postman-echo.com","content-length":"136","accept":"*/*","accept-encoding":"gzip","content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","user-agent":"php","x-forwarded-port":"443"},"json":{"{\"amount\":\"100\",\"currency\":\"DKK\",\"merchant\":\"INSERT_YOUR_MERCHANT_ID\",\"orderId\":\"Order_ID-123\",\"textreply\":\"true\",\"ticket\":\"1234567890\"}":""},"url":"https://postman-echo.com/post"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Update 30/11/2019:

Please try:

```
$data = array(
    'amount' => '100',
    'currency' => 'DKK',
    'merchant' => 'INSERT_YOUR_MERCHANT_ID',
    'orderId' => 'Order_ID-123',
    'textreply' => 'true',
    'ticket' => '1234567890'
    );

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://postman-echo.com/post",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>$data,
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

To debug PHP curl, please run and give the feedback:

```
$headers = array(
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
);

$data = array(
    'amount' => '100',
    'currency' => 'DKK',
    'merchant' => 'INSERT_YOUR_MERCHANT_ID',
    'orderId' => 'Order_ID-123',
    'textreply' => 'true',
    'ticket' => '1234567890'
    );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://postman-echo.com/post");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($info );
echo "</br>"; 
print_r($result );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I didn't know where to post the result, so I added it to my question. 
To have more outout I have changed the line:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
Could the problem be that the data is corrupted with \ in fornt of all the "

Comment: Please try my new update and feeback us if this work for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using [Guzzle HTTP Client](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/).

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->post('https://postman-echo.com/post', [
    'form_params' => [
        'amount' => '100',
        'currency' => 'DKK',
        'merchant' => 'INSERT_YOUR_MERCHANT_ID',
        'orderId' => 'Order_ID-123',
        'textreply' => 'true',
        'ticket' => '1234567890'
    ]
]);
```

Then, you can [use response](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#using-responses) as you wish.